# Cross Account Deployment to AWS ECS from AWS Codepipeline using CDK

Tags: aws-cdk

I've Codepipeline in Account A and AWS ECS in Account B. I've created two CDK stacks. One for Account A, creating Codepipeline stack. And second for Account B, creating ECS stack.
There is a IAM role present in Account B, which is used by Account A Codepipeline to deploy to ECS of Account B.

I need to pass ECS service name, ECS cluster name and IAM Role ARN of Account B to CDK stack of Account A. How I can do this using CDK?

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the cluster name and service name from A to B instead. That worked for me.